# How do i access a amazon ec2 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I was working with my client but as he wanted me to set up something on his amazon server and he provided me with a amazon url XXXX-utheast-1.compute.amazonaws.com something like this and with username and password but since I haven't done this previously how do I access the machine?

Comment: An Amazon EC2 instance is just like any other computer on the Internet. If it is running Linux, then connect via SSH. If it is running Windows, then use Remote Desktop to connect. What have you tried, and what problems are you facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below command in terminal (command prompt)

`ssh username@hostname`
it's ask about password enter passwrod